# Eclipse file associations for extensions with multiple periods

Tags: eclipse, file-extension

I have several Mako templates in my project that are named things like `header.html.tmpl` and `settings.py.tmpl`.  I would like to add file associations to Eclipse to open these with the appropriate editors.  For example, I would like `header.html.tmpl` to be opened in the HTML editor, `settings.py.tmpl` to be opened in the Python editor, etc.  I go to Preferences->File Associations and I try adding `*.py.tmpl` to the list but after I click "Ok" nothing happens and the desired extension does not appear in the list.  If I try instead using `.py.tmpl` I can add it to the list and add the Python editor to its associated editors but when I double-click a `.py.tmpl` file it doesn't use the correct editor.

Obviously it would probably work to just use `-tmpl` instead of `.tmpl`, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a way around this or can confirm that it's a bug/missing feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168573

Comment: Epic. **Eight** year old bug. It seems that this shouldn't be too hard to fix. Maybe I should find the time to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid, you didn't find the time ;) I've got similar problem with `*.html.erb`

Comment: ~14 years later, same problem (*.yaml.in)